# Itunes no longer in my order

Tags: itunes, playlist

I admit I am anal about organization, and have developed a nomenclature for all my play lists. Now they apparently sort based on the recent usage, not how I want to show.

Is there **any** way to go back to the way I like - in other words, in my case, alphabetical and then by the play list number. For example - Aqua 1, Aqua 2, etc.  My play lists are currently all over the place.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Could you edit a little into the post? iTunes runs on many OS, and there are lots of versions of the program. Maybe a screen shot of what is wrong uploaded is a quick way to get someone to dig into your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't about track order.  It is specifically referring to playlist order in the left column of playlist view.

Yes, this is a bug with the current iTunes (12.3.2).  When clicking on a playlist it tends to jump to the bottom of the folder list rather than staying alphabetically organized.  Hopefully this will get fixed with the next update.  But I am running El Capitan Beta 10.11.4 and it has not been fixed yet.  I've submitted multiple bug reports.

Quitting and restarting iTunes temporarily fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Open the iTunes list of items, then click on the name column. This will sort tracks by alphabetical/ reverse alphabetical order.